# What is the corresponding of UML operation properties(isQuery,Sequential,guarded, and concurrent) in Java Programming Language?

Tags: java, oop, uml, operation

in the UML you can specify the properties of class operations as 
`isQuery,Sequential,guarded, and concurrent`

What is the equivalent of these properties in Java?